# Deploy axis 2 web service on tomcat outside of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I have used the following link [Check This Link](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html)
to create web service. I used apache axis 2, tomcat and eclipse to develop it. I have been successful in the process.
Now I want to deploy the web service on tomcat outside of eclipse. I read that by creating the war file it can be done. But I have been unsuccessful. Can some tell me the steps to deploy a web service on tomcat on the outside. (NOTE I havent used sun-JAX WS )

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps which explains how to write axis2 service and deploy in tomcat, also not depend on eclipse. 
http://jayalalk.blogspot.com/2014/01/writing-axis2-services-and-deploying-in.html

Comment: Hi Thanks, but I was able to get it  running. But I am facing another problem now which i have mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717616/jsp-page-doesnt-run-in-web-service-client-using-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:\

1. Go to C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.41-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-6.0.41\conf and open tomcat-users.xml.

2.Enter the following inside the `<tomcat-users>` tag:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
   <role rolename="manager-script"/>
   <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
   <role rolename="manager-status"/>
   <role rolename="admin"/>
   <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

3. Restart apache tomcat.
4. Go to browser and type “localhost:8080” and click on “Tomcat Manager” under Administration in the top left panel.
5. Username:admin and password:admin
6. Scroll down to “WAR file to deploy” and Choose file to be deployed. Then click deploy.
7. The Application name should appear under the “Application” tab.