# JSP page doesnt run in web service client using tomcat

Tags: java, apache, web-services, jsp, tomcat

I have created a web service . The jsp page works perfectly fine on my local host using tomcat. Now when I deploy it on the virtual host  the services are getting deployed but the jsp page wont work. (sorry for the bad code its just for testing)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="com.sayhellotest.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<FORM ACTION="Hi.jsp" METHOD="POST">

<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="text1">
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
<%
RunnerHello t= new RunnerHello();
String name= t.printName(request.getParameter("text1"));
%>
<% out.println(name); %>
</FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

The client code is

```
public class RunnerHello {
    public String printName(String name) throws RemoteException  {
        SayHiStub stub= new SayHiStub();
        SayHiMethod hi= new SayHiMethod();
        hi.setName(name);
        SayHiMethodResponse hires = stub.sayHiMethod(hi);
        return hires.get_return();
    }
}
```

and the web service code is

```
public class SayHi {
    public String sayHiMethod(String name) {
        return "hi "+name;
    }

}
```

When I run it on localhost it works perfectly fine the jsp page run and give the output. But when  i run it on the main host the jsp doesnt work (though the services are uploaded). I get the error :

```
type Exception report

message org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 60000 ms

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 60000 ms
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:460)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 60000 ms
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:221)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:452)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:330)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.execute(OutInAxisOperation.java:294)
    com.rateexch.RateClassStub.getCurrencyInfo(RateClassStub.java:167)
    com.rateexch.RateRunner.getRateInfo(RateRunner.java:14)
    org.apache.jsp.Rate_jsp._jspService(Rate_jsp.java:81)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 60000 ms
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:314)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:201)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:452)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:330)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.execute(OutInAxisOperation.java:294)
    com.rateexch.RateClassStub.getCurrencyInfo(RateClassStub.java:167)
    com.rateexch.RateRunner.getRateInfo(RateRunner.java:14)
    org.apache.jsp.Rate_jsp._jspService(Rate_jsp.java:81)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 60000 ms
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:179)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:73)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:305)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:201)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:452)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:330)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.execute(OutInAxisOperation.java:294)
    com.rateexch.RateClassStub.getCurrencyInfo(RateClassStub.java:167)
    com.rateexch.RateRunner.getRateInfo(RateRunner.java:14)
    org.apache.jsp.Rate_jsp._jspService(Rate_jsp.java:81)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 60000 ms
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:154)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:124)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:706)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:386)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:558)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:176)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:73)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:305)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:201)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:452)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:330)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.execute(OutInAxisOperation.java:294)
    com.rateexch.RateClassStub.getCurrencyInfo(RateClassStub.java:167)
    com.rateexch.RateRunner.getRateInfo(RateRunner.java:14)
    org.apache.jsp.Rate_jsp._jspService(Rate_jsp.java:81)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:139)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:124)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:706)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:386)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:558)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:176)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:73)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:305)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:201)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:452)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:330)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.execute(OutInAxisOperation.java:294)
    com.rateexch.RateClassStub.getCurrencyInfo(RateClassStub.java:167)
    com.rateexch.RateRunner.getRateInfo(RateRunner.java:14)
    org.apache.jsp.Rate_jsp._jspService(Rate_jsp.java:81)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors clearly show that your jsp can't connect to the *webservice*.

As you are changing the domain of your *webservice* you need to change your connection configurations of your client in order to connect back to it.

Comment: What kind of changes should be made ?